# No internet on subnet after static routing setup

Tags: wireless-networking, router, routing, wireless-router, static-routes

I am trying to setup this network

```
[Dev PC]                   Internet
|                              ^
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
+------> [Home router] --------+
         192.168.0.0/24
              ^
              |
              |
              v
       [Cluster router]
        10.42.42.0/24
              |
              v
          L2 Switch
        --------------
         ^     ^     ^
         |     |     |
         |     |     |
    +----+     |     +----+
    |          |          |
    |          |          |
    V          V          V
[Node 1]    [Node 2]   [Node 3]
```

Dev PC in home router network and has `192.168.0.10`

Home router is ASUS RT-N66U and has `192.168.0.1` address

Cluster router has `10.42.42.1` address. This is TP-Link WR702N in **bridge** mode, connected via Wi-Fi to the home router and connected to L2 Switch via LAN port where Nodes1..3 are connected.
It has also manually set IP address in home router network:

[image: Manually assigned IP]

[image: I've also setup static routing:]

So, after this setup I can't ssh from dev PC to any of nodes and any of nodes don't have internet access.
What did I missed?

Comment: Are the cluster nodes on 192.168.0.0/24 or 10.42.42.0/24? Is there any reason why they can't or shouldn't be part of your 192.168.0.0/24 network?

Answer (score 0):

You should not configure the `[Cluster router]` but the `[Home router]` as Gateway.

Besides its IP in the home network 192.168.0.0/24 the `[Home router]` requires an IP in the 10.42.42.0/24 of the `[Cluster router]`.

Finally the the `[Home router]` connects the `[Node X]` to the internet or the home network. The `[Cluster Router]` is just the `Default Gateway` for the network 10.42.42.0/24.